# using http proxy with selenium Geckodriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I tried a few things but non of them worked. Anyone have a working example of using a HTTP proxy with Geckodriver for Selenium 3? I am using Java bindings

Here is what I tried

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.setHttpProxy("proxyip:proxyport");
        capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy);

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your work please?

Comment: Probably that's because you `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()` but next you have used `geckodriver.exe` in system.property

Comment: @Dev I tried it with firefox I still get an exception https://pastebin.com/YSt3626w

Comment: Okay, in the error stacktrace I can see `SessionNotCreatedException` exception which means that the marionatte is not even called. Is Firefox opening up through driver on your box?

Comment: yes firefox opens but does not load the page. If I don't pass it capabilities, then it will also load the page and I can interact with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable **proxy** with **Firefox** browser you need to create a *new profile* and pass it to the driver as follows:

- Setting up *HTTP* proxy:

  ```
  FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();         
  profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
  profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");     
  profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 3128); 
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
  ```
- Setting up *SSL* proxy:

  ```
  FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();         
  profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
  profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl", "localhost");     
  profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 3128); 
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
  ```

Comment: ```profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl", "localhost");
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 3128);```

Comment: This didn't work for me with the latest Firefox and Geckodriver as of today, but the method prescribed by the official docs worked: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/

Comment: @Motin, those docs only describe Chrome. How did you get it working with Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a proxy with authorization, then selenium will not be able to do it. Since selenium does not support working with alerts asking for a password. I wrote an add-on for Firefox with which you can solve both the problem with the proxy and with cookies and headers.

https://github.com/alexsok-bit/selenium_helper

You can use an add-on from the releases directory, it is already signed