# How to overcome sites that detecting Automated ChromeDriver?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I try to automate some steps using **selenium**, but when getting the **URL** the server rejected the request, here is my argument

```
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent="+getRandomeUserAgent())
opts.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,ar;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8'})
opts.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
opts.add_argument("--enable-cookies")
opts.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
opts.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
opts.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
opts.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
opts.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
opts.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])

driver = webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver( chromrdriverPath, options=opts)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)
driver.get(URL)
```

it works fine when using the normal browser (not-automated)
when sending the **HTTP request**, the site receives the request and redirects it to another page to check the browser if detected, refuse the request, and if not detected redirect to **WantedPage**.
What are techniques should I follow to treat with that?

Comment: As for the latest version of chromedriver, you can't. Because the website will always be able to detect webdriver in your program, even if your program isn't headless.

Comment: Is there any solution to solve this?, Or any **lib** or **browser** that I can use? @AgungWiyono

Comment: Here, you could use it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60252464/10144098