# How to make python selenium undetectable

Tags: python, selenium, bots, detection

I made a sneaker bot for nike.com site in python using selenium and I want to know if

there is any way to make selenium undetectable for Nike(so they can't notice that is an automated software and not a human behind) / supreme, or any other sites? I've heard about using request mode as an alternative,

and I've seen a post about how to make selenium undetectable, but most are for java and the methods are quite complicated.

And if there is no solution for hiding that I'm using selenium webdriver (Chrome), what would be the easiest way to be undetected on such websites?

EDIT: I want to mention that all what I know in python is using selenium and web scraping and I can't understand very much from the answers that I receive. Is my problem so hard to solve that I need to know so much information? Or, how long does it takes to understand these things? I was expecting an answer that says to add some lines in my code so that my bot don't be instantly detected by sites when openig a chrome driver, but it seems like is more than that. I don't even know where and what I should modify and I would like if you can redirect me to a link that takes this problem from 0.

Comment: Andrei welcome to SO. I wouldn't encourage scraping commercial sites, but for the sake of it, I think a good solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873022/how-to-make-selenium-script-undetectable-using-geckodriver-and-firefox-through-p). Also, try to make it sleep for a couple of seconds, between requests, instead of hammering their webserver

Answer (score 0):

Scraping the commercial sites with no permission can put you in legal trouble.however if you want to scrape the data from nike.com, introduce sleep and waits between requests to mimic the human behaviour on the site.

2.Web sites can also detect the robotic way of scraping the sites using monitor size.so I recommend to change the viewport to different size than default one.

3. Instead of using python and selenium, better find a an API used in nike.com using chrome developer tools or postman interceptor and hit it to get the data in one shot (most of the times, work lfows built using selenium will fail due to flakiness) P.S. I am not associated with Robotframework.org, I just love them the way they build the robot framework
4. If you still want to use selenium with python, quickly build the business flows to scrape the data and maintain easily, I recommend using Robot Framework (comes with inbuilt keywords used by selenium)