# Selenium: A specific page in website is coming blank / white screen

Tags: python, selenium

Using selenium I can browse through the entire website except for the login screen on a specific website. When I checked page source I see some js codes.

Using a normal chrome browser I can access the expected login screen. Can anyone help me to overcome this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seeing your profile you are truly averse with the idea on how SO works. i am pretty sure you can see the issues with your uestion if you try to answer yourself. Like what code you have tried ? What is page source code  ? etc. etc. Cheers !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that the website is detecting that you are using a bot and is blocking you from accessing its login screen for that reason. I can't know for sure that this is the reason because I haven't seen your issue in person, but most good websites don't like having non-human users interact with their pages, and a login page is exactly the type of page that the website would block you from accessing.

You can try to change some things to make Selenium less detectable by the website, but it's quite difficult and inconsistent at best. You can find some more information about achieving this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873022/how-to-make-selenium-script-undetectable-using-geckodriver-and-firefox-through-p), but I wouldn't expect too much.

Comment: Thanks, @Paul Taylor for redirecting to the correct link.

By doing something like this in selenium firefox it helped.
profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)