# Catching selenium error before it crashes in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I have a been having a problem with using selenium in my python code as the program keeps crashing.
I have tried to use try, except statement to catch the error so that
when it crashes I can still close it successfully but I have not been able to get it to work as the driver needs to be declared before it the exception statement
Please how can I catch the crash and close it. This is what I have tried

```
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
except Exception as e:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

It insist that **driver does not exists** and if I declare the driver before the exception statement with no argument it gives error
although I am using Chrome in this example but I intend to use it for firefox as well

Thanks

Comment: YOu need to provide the path for the chromedriver executable... https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/browser-automation-using-selenium/ may help

Comment: @PrakharParikh I have included it inide the options. Thanks very much really appreciate it

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Browsers are running in separate threads. Selenium only controls them.
It applies to any thread - you can send a signal, use sockets, etc, but if exception occurs in a different thread, you can only read this exception from the main thread - exception already occurred, so you can't control it.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium's driver might be used as context manager (i.e. harnessed using `with` statement), consider following example

```
with webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options) as driver:
    driver.get("http://www.example.com")
    print(driver.page_source)
```

When so used it should take care of ending both in case of crash and lack thereof, so you do not need to call `driver.close` and `driver.exit`.

Comment: I tried it it was not working. Thanks for the help

Comment: it did not work