# Python Selenium scraper rate limited (429) by Google

Tags: python, selenium, rate-limiting, http-status-code-429

I am scraping Google Patents with Selenium and, as expected, I am getting rate limited. I have tried all kinds of configurations (such as [How can I make a Selenium script undetectable using GeckoDriver and Firefox through Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873022/how-can-i-make-a-selenium-script-undetectable-using-geckodriver-and-firefox-thro), proxies, and so on), nothing works.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from utils import call_and_wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

def call_and_wait(_func=None, *, n=3):
    def decorator_wait(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper_repeat(*args, **kwargs):
            value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            time.sleep(n)
            return value
        return wrapper_repeat

    if _func is None:
        return decorator_wait
    else:
        return decorator_wait(_func)
class GooglePatentClient:
    def __init__(self):
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

        PROXY_HOST = "103.149.162.195"
        PROXY_PORT = "80"
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(PROXY_PORT))
        profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
        profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
        profile.update_preferences()
        desired = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, desired_capabilities=desired)

        self.driver = driver

    def connect(self, url='https://patents.google.com/'):
        self.driver.get(url)

    @call_and_wait(n=3)
    def query(self, q):
        elem = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys(q)
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    @call_and_wait(n=3)
    def filter_patent(self):
        self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                 value='#box > div:nth-child(2) > dropdown-menu:nth-child(2) > span > span:nth-child(1)').click()  # Click on type but
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                 value='/html/body/search-app/search-results/search-ui/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/workspace-ui/div[1]/workspace-ui-search/metadata-editor/div[4]/restrict-editor/div/div[2]/dropdown-menu[2]/iron-dropdown/div/div/div/div[1]').click()  # Click on patent

    @call_and_wait(n=3)
    def filter_english(self):
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                 value='/html/body/search-app/search-results/search-ui/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/workspace-ui/div[1]/workspace-ui-search/metadata-editor/div[4]/restrict-editor/div/div[1]/dropdown-menu[2]/span/span[1]').click()  # Click on Language
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                 value='/html/body/search-app/search-results/search-ui/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/workspace-ui/div[1]/workspace-ui-search/metadata-editor/div[4]/restrict-editor/div/div[1]/dropdown-menu[2]/iron-dropdown/div/div/div/div[1]').click()  # Click on English

    @call_and_wait(n=3)
    def download_csv(self):
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                 value='/html/body/search-app/search-results/search-ui/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/a').click()  # Click on Download button
```

and the main file:

```
from GooglePatentClient import GooglePatentClient    

queries = ['guz']
if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = GooglePatentClient()

    for query in queries:
        client.connect()
        client.query(query)
        client.filter_patent()
        client.filter_english()
        client.download_csv() # Should take some time
```

Unfortunately, after like 20 downloads, I am getting rate limited. It's strange for me that when I try to dowlnoad with normal Chrome/Firefox, I am not getting 429. It's detecting Selenium somehow but idk how can I surround the 429. Any ideas?

Comment: try sleeping in between requests. A human can't click as soon as the previous thing is done loading, which your code is doing.

Comment: I did, I forgot to add the call_and_wait function. It sleeps 3 secs between requests.