# Remove Bot-Identyfing Features from Firefox WebDriver Source Code?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver

One of the ways `WebDriver` [identifies itself as a bot to external websites](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#interface) is by setting the **webdriver-active flag** to true.

[image]

A user on SO [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52108199/16044298) that it is possible modify `Chrome Driver` source code to remove all bot-identifying attributes (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52108199/16044298) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41220267/16044298) response).

Is it possible to achieve a similar outcome w/ Firefox by modifying the source code of `Geckodriver`, `Firefox WebDriver` or perhaps both? I'm asking because there is currently [no way to conceal WebDriver using Firefox Options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70064475/16044298) without source code modification.

If we can somehow remove bot identifying features from the source code, we can prevent `WebDriver` from being identified as a bot without needing [to bundle TOR with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70064475/16044298).

While there's no getting around the fact that Selenium (in its present state) identifies itself, surely we can modify source code to remove all identification similar to how it's achieved in Chrome Driver?

Comment: source code is here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases  (You'd probably also want to change the proto-type name...)

Comment: Firefox may set the flag, though... it'll know when Marionette is used which may set the flag itself.  I don't really know... but any bot detection would be smarter than just relying on this, anyway.  They'll at the very least also detect the script injections/hooks.  (but have to target things specific to bots so add-ons/extensions wouldn't be flagged...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the discussion [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver) as suggested by different users to open the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) in a [Hex Editor](https://www.hhdsoftware.com/free-hex-editor) and edit the *document variables* replacing the `cdc_` and `$wdc_` string might be possible, but achiving the same with [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) may not be possible.

Moreover, the commands like [*execute_cdp_cmd()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191) and *Python* libraries like [**selenium-stealth**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/70133896#70133896) may not be currently supported by *GeckoDriver*.

---

The [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) source code can be easily downloaded from [mozilla / geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) page both in `zip` and `tar.gz` format. If you are on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) system you can unzip the downloaded file and find the the source code of different modules in the `...\geckodriver-0.30.0\src` directory:

[image: geckodriver_source_code]

---

Additionally, [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver) is made available under the [Mozilla Public License](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/). [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w/45510453#45510453) source code can also be found in [mozilla-central](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/testing/geckodriver) under **testing/geckodriver**.

[image: mozilla-central-files]

---

### WebDriver Specifications

Now as per [WebDriver W3C Editor's Draft](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#interface):

> > The ***webdriver-active flag*** is set to `true` when the user agent is under remote control. It is initially `false`.

[image: boolean_webdriver]

So there can be two possible ways to keep `webdriver` flag as `false` as:

- Remove the *`readonly`* attribute, so can be edited runtime. (as discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62520191/7429447))
- Strangle the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) from emitting the signals that the user agent is under remote control.

To me the second option looks pretty much viable as the most frequently updated tier is the second tier (`Selenium WebDriver.dll` and `WebDriver.Support.dll` modules). Since *App Studio* uses `C#` and `.Net` version *4.0* (before Selenium 4.1.0 (November 22, 2021)) to communicate with Selenium, you need to download the .Net 4.0 version of the Selenium modules. The [current stable version](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Selenium.WebDriver) being **4.1.0**. Once the zip file is downloaded, extract the content to a folder and navigate to the `net40` subfolder.

[image: net40]

Now, you can copy the `WebDriver.dll` and `WebDriver.Support.dll` files to the `bin` folder of the App Studio installation. e.g, `C:\ibi\AppStudio82\bin` and make the required changes.

As an alternative, you can also download the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver), copy the `.Net 4.0` content of the **NuGet** package into the bin folder of the App Studio installation and make the required changes.

---

### tl; dr

- [*Building geckodriver*](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Building.html#building-geckodriver)
- [Testing geckodriver](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Testing.html#testing-geckodriver)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is the second option to strangle WebDriver only available in .net framework or in Java too? As I am using the Java version of Selenium. Thanks.