# Download images from webpage using RSelenium in R

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium, imagedownload

I want to download images from a webpage using RSelenium in R. I have extracted information of all the images using this code

`Images_Extract <- remDr$findElements(using = "css selector", value = "xxx")`

I have used the appropriate CSS selector (xxx) value to get the information of images. But, I am stuck at the next step of extracting them from Images_Extract and downloading them. Steps for doing this would be helpful.

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/70064475/7731623

Comment: Provide link to webpage