# How to use Selenium with Firefox Proxy in Selenium 4.x

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, proxy, geckodriver

I need to pass through options as profiles are deprecated.
I am trying to use FF to proxy to a secure browser. However, I ran into a problem, which is described below:

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

socks = '127.0.0.1:9050'
profile_path = '~/Library/Application\ Support/TorBrowser-Data/Browser/tjv18qgq.default'
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
proxy = Proxy({
    "proxyType": 'manual',
    "httpProxy": socks,
    "sslProxy": socks,
    "noProxy": ''
})
proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = False
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
options.set_capability("proxy", proxy)
service = Service(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)

driver.get('https://check.torproject.org/')
element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h1')
if element.text == 'Sorry. You are not using Tor.':
    print('Not connected')
    driver.close()
```

My output:

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current firefox version is 95.0
Get LATEST geckodriver version for 95.0 firefox
Driver [/Users//.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/macos/v0.30.0/geckodriver] found in cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//dev/awesomeCRM/Backend/octopus-py/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
  File "/Users//dev/awesomeCRM/Backend/octopus-py/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 179, in init
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/Users//dev/awesomeCRM/Backend/octopus-py/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 268, in init
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users//dev/awesomeCRM/Backend/octopus-py/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 356, in start_session
    w3c_caps = _make_w3c_caps(capabilities)
  File "/Users//dev/awesomeCRM/Backend/octopus-py/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 102, in _make_w3c_caps
    if caps.get('proxy') and caps['proxy'].get('proxyType'):
AttributeError: 'Proxy' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: I am using selenium 4x (https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/)

Answer (score 5):

[`FirefoxProfile()` have been *Deprecated*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571950/deprecationwarning-firefox-profile-has-been-deprecated-please-pass-in-an-optio/70088853#70088853) and with [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) to use a *custom profile* you have to use an instance of `Options`.

---

The configurations which was earlier set through `profile.set_preference()` now can be set through **`options.set_preference()`** as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

profile_path = r'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\s8543x41.default-release'
options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', False)
service = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe')
driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

---

### tl; dr

[Setting a custom profile](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/driver_specific_capabilities/#setting-a-custom-profile)

---

### Outro

[using http proxy with selenium Geckodriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960301/using-http-proxy-with-selenium-geckodriver/43961118#43961118)

Comment: The `tl;dr` link does not work now. You can use this link instead: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/firefox/#setting-a-custom-profile

Answer (score 0):

Firefox Proxy Setting for selenium==4.15.2

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "127.0.0.1")
options.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 7890)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 7890)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', False)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", "127.0.0.1")
options.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", 7890)
```